# Groovy interpolate multiline string in java annotation

Tags: java, groovy, compiler-errors, jvm, spock

Is possible to compile groovy code where I have @Sql annotation with constant?

The code below is simple test, written in Spock.

```groovy
@Sql(statements = ["""
         INSERT INTO pracownik ($Fields.KOMPETENCJA_ID, nr_ewid) 
                                values (1, 'A');
         INSERT INTO typ_zadania (id, kod) values (1, 'KOD');
"""]
)
def "should add new qualification"() { 
  //test code omitted
}
```

When I want to run test method i get error while compilation:

> Groovyc: Expected '   INSERT INTO pracownik ($Fields.KOMPETENCJA_ID,
>   nr_ewid) 
>                                          values (1, 'A'); INSERT INTO typ_zadania (id, kod) values (1, 'KOD'); to be an inline constant of
>   type java.lang.String in @org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.Sql`

I think that multiline string with dollar sign is evalueted to GString object, but statements fields is type of array of string.

Can I have in groovy code with java annotation constants in multiline string?

Answer (score 5):

The problem you are facing has nothing to do with multiline String - the compiler expects that the value passed to the `statement` attribute is an inline constant. `GString` with interpolated variables does not satisfy this expectation. You would see exactly the same compilation error if you write a single line `GString` that contains interpolated values from `Fields` class field.

It seems like your intention was to get the column name associated with `Fields.KOMPETENCJA_ID`. Replace it with the expected value, so there is no interpolation needed. Something like this:

```groovy
@Sql(statements = """
        INSERT INTO pracownik (kompetencja_id, nr_ewid) 
                               values (1, 'A');
        INSERT INTO typ_zadania (id, kod) values (1, 'KOD');
""")
def "should add new qualification"() {
    //test code omitted
}
```

> One interesting fact about Groovy. The double quote `"` is usually used to represent `GString` type. However, Groovy compiler checks if the string contains any variables like `${variableName}` to do the interpolation. If it finds any, it uses `GString` as a type, and `String` otherwise.

Comment: Hi, My intention was not to get column name but value of id. (I made mistake it should be INSERT INTO pracownik (id, nr_ewid) 
                                values ($Fields.KOMPETENCJA_ID, 'A');   but does not change meaning. Ok so compiler do inline copmile time constant and it seems to impossible to have any constant in my annotation?

Comment: @K2milJ33 You get the idea, but let's rephrase it correctly - the annotation's attribute value must be constant. You can use a static final variable reference, but this variable has to be constant as well. It means that its value cannot be constructed as a result of calling any particular method, but has to be defined inline. This limitation is not Groovy specific, but it comes directly from Java.

Comment: static class Fields {
        static final PRACOWNIK_ID = 1L
        static final TYP_ZADANIA_ID = 1L
        static final KOMPETENCJA_ID = 1L
    }                                                                                                                                      var KOMPETENCJA_ID is constant...

Comment: @K2milJ33 You got _"You can use a static final variable reference, but this variable has to be constant as well."_ wrong. It means that you can create a constant string in static final field and you can use it like `@Sql(statements = myConstantStatement)` where `myConstantStatement` is nothing else than constant string. In your case, however, you add constant strings to an interpolated GString which is not a constant construct. The same compilation error occurs when you try something like this: `@Sql(statements = String.format("--My SQL here--"))`. It doesn't matter if it is extracted to a var

Comment: The example that uses `String.format()` also shows one limitation - for the compiler, it doesn't make any difference if a string returned by `String.format()` method uses any arguments like e.g. `String.format("Hello, %s", "John")`. The constant string is only a string like `"Hello, John"`. Expressions like `String.format("Hello, John")` or `String.format("Hello, %s", "John")` don't produce constant strings from the compiler perspective. And Java annoations work only with constant strings - this is why you can't use interpolated Groovy strings as well.

Comment: Thank you Szymon.